# Does same user on each iteration refers to same IP address

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter, we have the option "Same user on each iteration" that falls under the loop in threads.  Does same user implies same IP address?

How can I generate different users with different IP address.  I don`t need any kind of login,  just different IPs.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't.

Under the "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler there is a "Source address" input field where you can provide the desired IP address which will be used as the origin:

[image]

The field value can be normally parameterized using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) according to your needs.

Remember only one "small" constraint: the IP address (or [IP alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing)) **must be present at the operating system level**, you cannot just put a random IP there. Refer to your operating system documentation to learn how to add IP addresses and/or aliases.

More information: [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter/)